# SED in Bash Script to copy the content of variable in a file

Tags: bash, sed

I need to copy the content of a variable in the top of other file without deleting the text of the file.

I have this code:

```
var=$(<file.txt)
sed -i -e '1i$var' file2
```

But only writes the text "$var" in the first line of file2, not the total content of var.

Any idea?.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use double quotes for shell to expand variables:

```
sed -i -e "1i$var" file2
```

btw you can avoid sed by using:

```
cat file.txt file2 > _tmp && mv _tmp file2
```

Comment: With sed -i -e "1i$var" file2 I have and error, but with cat works, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to add some fixed values after the variable or multiple variables, you have to use both **double quotes** around the expression and **curly brackets** around your vars.

```
sed -i "1s/^/${var}FIXEDTEXTHERE /" file2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cat file.txt <> file2
```

without temp file